# Convex optimization: affine equality constraints into inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, constraint-programming

I have the following problem:

\begin{equation} 
\begin{array}{cll}
\displaystyle \min_{ \mathbf{x} } & & \displaystyle f(\mathbf{x}) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & & \mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{C} \\
& & \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}=0.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

with $\mathcal{C}$ closed and convex, $f(\mathbf{x})$ monotonically increasing and convex.

Can I change the affine equality constraint into inequality $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\geq0$? If not , there exists a case in which it holds?

How can I demonstrate it? Maybe some references could be useful.

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious why you would even *hope* that making such a wholesale change to a problem could be accomplished without changing its result. Is there a specific application, perhaps, where it is claimed that you can do this?

Comment: Yes, it is similar to the convexification of the opf, but here we have a linear convex constraint

Comment: Right, but the reason you convexify a non-convex constraint is because you *have* to if you want tractability. There's no payoff here: changing from an equation to inequality doesn't fundamentally alter tractability.

Comment: Right but the problem with inequality constraints is easier to solve in iterative way (in particular I'm looking for a decentralized solution), so I wanted to know when it it's possible to do this simplification, due to the fact that in some case MATLAB gives the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily get the same solution.

Consider $C$ to be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the corresponding maximization problem where $f$ is concave and we maximize instead(the idea is the same between concave maximization and convex minimization - I just wrote this solution seeing concave maximization). $A = [1 ,1]^T$, $b = 0$, and $f(x) = [1 , 1]^T $x$.

Then, the optimal value for the objective is zero, and any optimizing $x$ must be orthogonal to $[1, 1]^T$. Changing the inequality to be greater than or equal to $0$ specifies any vector in one of the half ball specified by the direction of $[1,1]^T$ is a $x$ which meats the constraints, and the objective is non-zero (in fact, it is maximized for $x = 1/\sqrt{2} [1, 1]^T$.

Back to the convex minimization case:

Since the constraint set is larger for the inequality case than the equality case, you can say the optimal solution for the inequality case is at least as small as the solution for the equality case.

Comment: I didn't get what you said about minimization case.

Comment: In the maximization problem you need to change the inequality in less or equal to!!!!!!

Comment: The set $S_1 = \{ x : x \in C, Ax -b = 0\}$ is a subset of  $S_2 \{ x : x \in C, Ax -b \geq 0\}$. Thus, minimizing $f$ over $S_1$ will give a result which is at least as large as minimizing over $S_2$. And you can tweak the argument slightly to fit the form exactly as you specified.

Comment: The interesting question here is whether there is some general transformation of the original form into a convex problem with a linear inequality constraint. The observation that replacing an equality with an inequality enlarges the search space is immediate and irrelevant.

Comment: @Batman : This statement is true for everything  `Since the constraint set is larger for the inequality case than the equality case, you can say the optimal solution for the inequality case is at least as small as the solution for the equality case` , doesnt matter convex or not